# Changing the size of a rect messes up my landing code

Tags: java

When you click on the screen, my player(rect) gets dropped by gravity.  But if you land on my platform(rect) you dont fall off the screen and die.

Where ever the player lands on the platform where he stays

`player.getX()`
This is a getter to get rectangle.left of the player.
This used to work for the landing

But then I changed the players size from (100,100) to (125,125). For some reason this makes the player move to the left when ever you land

> Collision Process

```
public boolean playerCollide(RectPlayer player) {
        return RectF.intersects(rectangle, player.getRectangle()) && player.getRectangle().bottom < rectangle.bottom;
    }
```

> Landing on the platform

```
            if (o1 != null && !onPlatform) {
                gameOverTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                onPlatform = true;
                starsShow = false;
                onPlatformObject = o1;
                xcollide = player.getX();
            } else if (onPlatform) {
                playerPoint = new Point((int)onPlatformObject.getRectangle().right - player.getX(), (int) onPlatformObject.getRectangle().top - 52);
                player.update(playerPoint);
            } else if (!onPlatform) {
                player.update();
            }
```

There is no error message and it used to work, so im confused

Comment: And also, did you write the game engine yourself? If you didn't, It would be helpful to know what you are working with and maybe tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I wrote it myself @mumpitz

Comment: `playerPoint = new Point((int)onPlatformObject.getRectangle().right - player.getX() ...` are you modifying the x coordinate of the player when it hits the platform, here?

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca i am not modifying anything with ~~~player.getX()~~~ that code was just some testing